# Python ValueError for yfinance code regarding date format

Tags: python, stock, yahoo, yfinance, pytorch-forecasting

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import pandas_datareader as data
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from keras.models import load_model
import streamlit as st 
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime

yf.pdr_override()
start = datetime(2010,11,11) #2010-01-01
end = datetime(2019,12,31)   #2019-12-31

st.title('Stock Trend Prediction')
user_input = st.text_input('Enter Stock Ticker', 'AAPL')
df = pdr.DataReader(user_input,'yahoo', start, end)

#Describing data
st.subheader('data from 2010 - 2019')
st.write(df.describe())
```

ValueError: time data 'yahoo' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'`
please help

i tried changing date format from y-m-d to d-m-y however it wont work

i just want to get the program running